# I'm lost: NullPointerException - Parsing XML for XLS

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, nullpointerexception, spreadsheet

Sorry, I have been trying to research and figure this out on my own, but I'm still and wet behind the ears when it comes to Java and it's not clicking for me yet:

I'm working on a program to parse an XML document and convert contents to spreadsheet cells.  I've gotten it to work well with first and last names, but many of the nodes for middle name are empty in XML and this generates the NullPointerException error - I assume because the NULL value prevents the code from working.  I've tried a few different statements to check for NULL and assign an empty string when that occurs, but nothing I've tried works - it either gives that error still, or results in all middle names being blank (when there are a few in the XML doc that do include a middle name).

I was going to post an image of some of the XML doc, but it won't let me because my rep isn't high enough.  So I'm trying to enter it as 'code sample' here, hopefully there are no typos:

```
-<PersonInfos>
 -<PersonInfoList>
  -<PersonInfo>
    <FirstName>Kimberly</FirstName>
    <MiddleName>Diana</MiddleName>
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
   </PersonInfo>
  -<PersonInfo>
    <FirstName>Charlie</FirstName>
    <MiddleName/>
    <LastName>Nelson</LastName>
   </PersonInfo>
```

Some of my code below - without any type of NULL check.

What type of IF...NULL statement do I need to insert?  Thanks in advance!!

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {                

    HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
    rows = spreadSheet.createRow(i+1);

    HSSFCell cell0 = rows.createCell(0);        
    cell0.setCellValue(((Element) (nodeList.item(i)))       
            .getElementsByTagName("FirstName").item(0)
            .getFirstChild().getNodeValue());

    HSSFCell cell1 = rows.createCell(1);
    cell1.setCellValue(((Element) (nodeList.item(i)))       
                .getElementsByTagName("MiddleName").item(0)
                .getFirstChild().getNodeValue());

    HSSFCell cell2 = rows.createCell(2);        
    cell2.setCellValue(((Element) (nodeList.item(i)))       
            .getElementsByTagName("LastName").item(0)
            .getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
}
```

Comment: Assuming you've searched on the issue of solving NullPointerExceptions (NPE), then you already know that the key to solving them is to inspect the line that throws them. And if you haven't searched this before coming here, you should do so (and similarly for future posts). So, what line is it?

Comment: Sorry - yes, I've run some searches and I'm almost positive the MiddleName node is what's causing the problem.  Because I started with just FirstName and LastName nodes (wasn't going to even use the middle name data) and everything worked peachy.  But almost all of the data has 1st and last names, but most are missing middle names.

The npe error appears on the last line of the MiddleName code, where I'm trying to assign the value to the cell1 variable.

Comment: I know I need some kind of 'if (xxx == null)' statement (or !=null) before the MiddleName / cell1 assignment, so I can assign "" as a string if it is null.  I just can't figure out how to word that statement.  I keep getting errors, or I get no error but no middle names populate (not even the ones that have that name).

Comment: does it tell you which line the exception is thrown from?

Comment: You should un-chain your offending code, and then use a debugger or println statements to **identify which key variable is null**. Til you do that, this question is unanswerable.

Comment: The exception is thrown from the last line under the cell1 statement:

.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());

Comment: if you do stuff like put `((Element(nodeList.item(i))).getElementsByTagName("MiddleName")` into a variable, it might be easier to find which of the values is null using your debugger

Comment: Again, unchain that code. Yes, chained method calls compresses your code, but it also makes it harder to debug since multiple lines are compressed to one line. Spread that code over several lines, test which variable is null.

Comment: Thank you HFoE, I see what you mean now.  I'll try that out and see if I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
if(nodeList.item(i).getElementsByTagName("MiddleName").item(0).getFirstChild() == null) {
   here set the value to ""
}
```